# visual studio copy paste iterative numbers

Tags: visual-studio, iterator, copy-paste

In Visual Studio, is there a simple and quick way to copy something like this:

```
var name1 
var name2
var name3
var name4
```

and paste to get:

```
var name5 
var name6
var name7
var name8
```

Goes against programming fundamentals, but in the context of testing this would be useful.

Comment: In MS-Excel, you can type the first two lines then highlight the two cells and drag the copy block in the bottom right corner to get an incremented list.  It's not in visual studio, but you can save a lot of typing.

Comment: Copy into Excel. Select the four cells. Drag the little black square (at the bottom of the selected group) down over some more cells. Copy and paste back into Visual Studio.

Comment: Very nice, I think that will suffice, but it would be nice to have this in some plugin to visual studio